# Android NDK linking with shared .so

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have a test application I am trying to link with ibicuuc and libicui18n. (This is the first step in a larger project).

I am including these in my project as prebuilt libraries

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libicuuc libicui18n
```

compiled as-is from the git repository:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu4c/
```

This is the build log from clean:

```
$ ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libicui18n.so <= /usr/local/opt/android/libs/libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libicui18n.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libicui18n.so
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libicuuc.so <= /usr/local/opt/android/libs/libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libicuuc.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libicuuc.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: main <= main.cc
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libmain.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmain.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
```

Which looks good and as a test If I miss out the libs from LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES the build fails as expected

```
/usr/local/opt/android/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/main.o: in function test_icu():jni/src/main.cc:71: error: undefined reference to 'unum_countAvailable_53'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So all well and good, but when the application is run, the symbol is not found:

```
D/dalvikvm( 7846): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/net.alphawave.test.nativelibs-1/libmain.so 0x41e646a0
E/dalvikvm( 7846): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libmain.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "unum_countAvailable_53" referenced by "libmain.so"...
W/dalvikvm( 7846): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/test/nativelibs/NativeLibs;
W/dalvikvm( 7846): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/test/nativelibs/NativeLibs;)
D/AndroidRuntime( 7846): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 7846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41591ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7846): Process: com.example.test.nativelibs, PID: 7846
E/AndroidRuntime( 7846): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "unum_countAvailable_53" referenced by "libmain.so"...
```

I havd tried pre-loading these libraries, but this does not seem to help:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("icuuc");
    System.loadLibrary("icui18n");
    System.loadLibrary("main");
}
```

this results in:

```
D/dalvikvm( 8277): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicuuc.so 0x41e6d310
D/dalvikvm( 8277): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicuuc.so 0x41e6d310
D/dalvikvm( 8277): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicuuc.so 0x41e6d310, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 8277): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicui18n.so 0x41e6d310
D/dalvikvm( 8277): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicui18n.so 0x41e6d310
D/dalvikvm( 8277): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libicui18n.so 0x41e6d310, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 8277): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libmain.so 0x41e6d310
E/dalvikvm( 8277): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.test.nativelibs-1/libmain.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "unum_countAvailable_53" referenced by "libmain.so"...
```

The symbol is present in the icui18n library:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf -aW libicui18n.so | grep unum_countAvailable 
3700: 000ee8a9     4 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 unum_countAvailable_53
```

What am I missing? or is there some mod needed to the icu* build?

Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like you've probably just not build icu correctly. Try running `readelf -sW EACH_LIB | grep unum_countAvailable` to see if either library contains the symbol.

Comment: Hi, the symbol is present in the icui18n lib (added note above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a mismatch between the linked libraries (version 53) and the /system libraries (version 51), and the run-time linker is using the latter.

I have asked a revised question!